# PHPExcel EXTEND the formatted cells depending on a count

Tags: php, phpexcel

What is does is skips `C19`. I need help making it catch row 19 and col C to H and move it the be the last after the `$client_properties_count;` how will i do that?

Comment: No, the format won't change unless you change it.... if a cell doesn't have any formatting, and you want it formatted, then you need to write the code to set that formatting. You may find the Worksheet's `getStyle()` and `duplicateStyle()` methods useful

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for the advice, what would be the best approach to duplicateStyle() only for the array keys total, abrupt and owner income? for all of the array data that get inserted. make sure it duplicates the style Thanks

Comment: Read the styling for cell C17 into a variable first. Calculate the dimensions of the array that you're going to insert and convert those to Excel range coordinates from offset C17, write your data array, then apply the saved style to that range

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks, I got it done now. however. it dont push down my cells like i was expected like Shift:=xlDown does. instead. my last row which has different format gets overwritten.. I can't find anything like shifting down the rows and pushing them on PHPExcel.. I will add a screnshot of what i mean now

Comment: The worksheet has a method `insertNewRowBefore()` that you can use to insert 1 or more rows

Comment: @MarkBaker would you please take a look at my last piece of code and help me put it together as an answer? I'd be very Thankful. Thanks for your time.